# What is the point of archive in the Hangouts messaging app?

Tags: google-hangouts, instant-messaging

Is the archive in Hangouts storing the messages somewhere or is it just hiding them from the inbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just hides them from the inbox, which means they aren't copied somewhere else. For more informations check out Google support page [here](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3112142?hl=en).